# Power BI Embed code, created from SharePoint list

Tags: powerbi

I know how to find and add the embed code to the SharePoint online web part when you create a report from PowerBi. However, I need help finding the embed code when I make a report from the SharePoint list. Under the file section, I can only see Save and Save as options

[image]